# jQuery mobile - allow scrolling only when side panel is closed?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-panel

I don't want user to scroll when any side bar is open. They should scroll once it closed.

I've use below code but its not working on android mobile device

```
$(document).bind('panelopen', function (e, data) {     
        $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
    });

    $(document).bind('panelclose', function (e, data) {         
        $('body').css("overflow", "auto");
    });
```

Comment: When you say its not working, what do you mean?

Comment: @shanabus means when side panel is open it is scrolling. it should not be scroll.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `overflow` option never worked for me. I had to rely on the `touchmove` event of the `body`. I changed your `pageinit` event to this :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function (event) {   

    $("#defaultpanel").on("panelopen", function (event, ui) { 
        //setting overflow : hidden and binding "touchmove" with event which returns false
        $('body').css("overflow", "hidden").on("touchmove", stopScroll);
    });

    $("#defaultpanel").on("panelclose", function (event, ui) {
        //remove the overflow: hidden property. Also, remove the "touchmove" event. 
        $('body').css("overflow", "auto").off("touchmove");
    });

    function stopScroll() {
        return false;
    }    
});
```

So when the panel opens, the `overflow` property is changed, after which the `touchmove` event is bound to `body`. The `stopScroll` function, which prevents default action of our touch screen, is bound to the `touchmove` event of body.

When the panel closes, you'll have to `unbind` that `touchmove` event from `body` to restore your scroll.

Works on Galaxy S3, Xperia S, Nexus 4 phones and Nexus 7 tablet.

<kbd>[Here's the code at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/azavup/14/edit)</kbd>

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to the content behind the panel only? As it is here is is stopping the panel and the content behind it from scrolling but I want the panel to be able to scroll while the background scrolling is disabled. I have tried to change 'body' to 'content' and to the id of the div my content is within but it doesn't work.

Comment: To add to this I mean it doesn't work on mobile devices, it seems to on a desktop browser.

Answer (score 2):

The latest jQuery Mobile API docs say to use

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "panelopen", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Could you try that?  It may work using the `on()` method instead of the older `bind()` approach.  Also, perhaps you could bind the overlflow change to a child of body instead of the body element.  Its hard to give a more specific solution without seeing more of your code.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-open

**UPDATE**

Here is a link to the jsbin with working solution: http://jsbin.com/azavup/2/

The exact JS used is below:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#page1", function( event ) {

  $( "#defaultpanel" ).on( "panelopen", function( event, ui ) {
    //console.log("i am open");
    $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
  } );

  $( "#defaultpanel" ).on( "panelclose", function( event, ui ) {
    //console.log("i am close");
    $('body').css("overflow", "auto");
  } );

});
```

So maybe you just need to change your `panelopen`/`panelclose` binding to the actual panel selector, not the `document`.  That works.

Comment: yes I've checked that also.... $( "#sidebar" ).on( "panelbeforeopen", function( event, ui ) {
              $('html body').css("overflow", "hidden");   
    });....but its not working

Comment: Please see updated answer with working example. Tested in galaxy S3.

Comment: I've implemented like that but it still scrolls. I've tested in micromax canvas 2...

Comment: Strange thing is its working on my Desktop. it was also working with previous solution.

Comment: Awesome! This lets me use swipe events elsewhere and keep the panel from scrolling. Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```js
$('#nav-panel').panel({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        //check the event alert('kpl');
        $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        //check the event alert('kpl1');
        $('body').unbind('touchmove');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this CSS :

```
.ui-panel.ui-panel-open {
   position:fixed;
}

.ui-panel-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

and adding this attribute to your  element :

```
data-position-fixed="true"
```

will fix the problem. (It did for me)