# jQuery mobile - allow only vertical scrolling when side panel is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946006/jquery-mobile-allow-scrolling-only-when-side-panel-is-closed) I want to allow only vertical scroll.

The following code will disable all touch moves on a panel.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#form1", function (event) {
    $("#navmenu").on("panelopen", function (event, ui) {
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden").on("touchmove", stopScroll);
    });
    $("#navmenu").on("panelclose", function (event, ui) {
        $("body").css("overflow", "auto").off("touchmove");
    });

    function stopScroll() {
        return false;
    }
});
```

How can I use "overflow-x: hidden" with the stopScroll function to allow vertical scroll and disable horizontal?

Thanks.

Comment: page always scrolls vertically. you mean disable swipe left and right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this

```
$("html, body").css("overflowX", "hidden");
```

Better make a css separate for mobile.

Comment: I want to disable horizontal scroll when the panel is opened and allow horizontal scroll when the panel is closed.
css("overflow-x", "hidden") is required, but I don't know how to combine this with the stopScroll function.

Comment: Unfortunately $("html, body").css("overflow-x", "hidden"); is not working without disabling touchmove.

Comment: @joyspeed you mean to disable `touchmove`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('panelopen', '[data-role="panel"]',function (event) {
    document.ontouchmove = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}).on('panelclose', '[data-role="panel"]', function (event) {
        document.ontouchmove = function(e) {
             return true;
        }
    });
```